# jmh output prints "??" for average times

Tags: java, unicode, jmh

I'm using JMH on Windows 7.  I'm trying to generate average times output.  I've tried running the built jar in either a cygwin mintty or a DOS cmd shell.  In both cases, it prints out values like "10?? s/op".

I've tried several things to try to fix this.  I would also like to see if I could get it to report measurements in terms of milliseconds or microseconds, but I'm not going to bother until I can be sure that it's even reporting real data.

This is most likely a character encoding problem, but I don't understand how to fix it.  I tried examining the output with a hex viewer, and those characters really are "?" characters.  I've seen one other SO posting with a similar problem ([Strange output when using JMH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292059/strange-output-when-using-jmh)), but the information in that posting and answer didn't help me.

Comment: Are you sure that the terminal and font you're using support extended Unicode?

Comment: Of course I'm not sure. How would I even know?

Comment: You've linked to an answer that explains the cause of this values. You will find more detailed information on how to fix it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? The question you link to did not help me either, since this is more than just a console issue - if I run my jar and direct the output to a file rather than the screen it still renders question marks, regardless of that file's encoding.